# Heidegger's origin of the work of art and Nietzsche's Dionysian vs. Apollonian forces in art

Tags: nietzsche, heidegger, art

In "Origin of the Work of Art" ( *der Ursprung des Kunstwerkes*),  Heidegger talks about a piece of art as something that is both **world** and **earth**. These two are in a constant battle, in which they drive each other to self-preservation of its being, world being that wants to 'expose' and earth being that wants to 'cover up'.

Is this comparable to Nietzsche's description of the Dionysian and Apollonian forces in art?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia, it was Nietzsches ideas that prompted Heideggers; but whereas N placed Art higher than Thinking; H placed them at the same level but apart.